# What is the word to signify "someone is yet having that specific relationship with me"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I'm looking for a word to express my thought or feeling. Say for example, I'm talking or writing about my life. Therein, I've to say about my wife ( who is **yet** my wife in legal terms or so & **still** not divorced ). Whenever I say about her, I want the reader or listener should get the feel that although she is currently my wife but she should have been divorced from me **yet**. So I came up to something like I can say "she is my yet wife; my yet wife told". But this is not literally correct. So, I need a word which can substitute "yet".

I'm elaborating a bit on the meaning of "yet" which I used as adjective for "wife" as in "yet wife". Say, you say someone to leave your house. After 1 hour I go and see he is still there at your house and hasn't left yet. Then I come to say you that see that person hasn't left your house **yet**. That's what I want to imply that she is my wife **yet** though she should have been divorced from me a long time back.

Can one say the right way of expressing that thought or feeling.

Comment: Are you trying to express the thought that divorce is imminent - that you know it will be happening soon? Or are you trying to say that you are aware that you're married now but things might change?

Comment: @Spratty I meant the latter, I.e. things might change, rather to be more precise I want to express that I want the divorce to happen and not only that, rather the divorce should have happened a long time ago ( which would have been justice to me ) but due to corruption and hooliganism by law and order enforcing officials including police, administration and judiciary, that didn't happen.

Comment: "She is *still* my wife". example: *She is still my wife, but at this moment we are living in separate houses*.

Comment: @Ravi In that case, while I don't believe there is a single-word answer in British English to convey all that meaning, I could see "my soon-to-be ex wife" indicating that a) you are currently married; b) you are not happy about it; and c) you are taking steps to end that state of affairs. I'm sure that with your clarification someone will come up with something more elegant but that's the first thing I though of.

Comment: If you are legally married, but you and your wife no longer consider that you have an ongoing marital enterprise, you might considered calling your legal spouse your *estranged* wife.

Comment: "my soon-to-be ex-wife" ?

Comment: Spratty and deadrat have good suggestions.  You could also use adjectives that suggest the relationship is temporary (soon to be terminated), like  "ad interim. "

Comment: @Spratty by saying " soon-to-be ex wife", I'm trying to signify something which is currently not there but a future possibility or future happening. Rather I want to signify what the status is there currently. Hey Spratty what about my usage "yet wife", as it's not literally right I will add in my discourse when I use for the 1st time, that by "yet" I mean "currently".

Comment: @Ravi, you wouldn't say "yet wife" - that's not a valid construction for what you want to say. You could say "current wife", which expresses the fact that she's your wife _now_, and the fact you are stressing the fact that she is your wife _now_ would indicate to listeners you don't necessarily anticipate that situation continuing.

Comment: You could say, "She's my wife 'pro tem.'"

Comment: @Elian I've edited my Q to make it more clear what I want. Though "pro tem" is what can be used if no other substitute I get. But what exactly I'm looking for is a word that would match the meaning of 'yet', i.e. it should mean that she is currently my wife although she should have been divorced a long back.

Comment: @Spratty I've edited my Q for clarity.

Comment: In some cases where you use _yet_, I don't think the word conveys the right meaning. I'd say _ who is **still** my wife in legal terms or so & not **yet** divorced _, _she should have been divorced from me **already** _ and _I want to imply that she is **still** my wife _.

Comment: This question is still unclear about the context of the narrative _and_ the time frame of events _and_ the subject of the word. 1) are you writing a biography (about your own past) or are you writing about yourself and relations right now? 2) at what time does the events and separately the reported speech occur in the narrative 3) do you want a word/words for the state of marriage or just markers for time that will work for any relation (marriage, sickness, stock market level, etc)?

Comment: @oerkelens yes, thanks a lot for the comment. It's useful.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean that you want to say that at the time of the event you are describing, they were your wife, but she is no longer?

In which case, you would say she was your **then-wife**. You may then qualify that by saying 'She was my **then-wife**, now ex-wife'. Or, you can just say then-wife, then not qualify it as to what your current status is with her, preserving some mystery as to what happened.

A common example is 'My **then-girlfriend**, now wife told me that...'

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word you are looking for is **fiancée**

```
a woman engaged to be married
```

For a man, it would be **fiancé**. These words are used to describe a couple who is going to marry in the future because they have already decided to do so. Two people (boyfriend and girlfriend) who love each other are **fiancé** and **fiancée** after deciding to marry and before actually becoming husband and wife.

EDIT: I now realize that my answer was completely wrong. However, I want to own up to my mistakes by keeping my original answer here as well as a new one. There's a popular phrase for women who are about to be married called **soon-to-be mrs**. So you could potentially describe your wife, as of now, as **soon-to-be ex-wife** or **soon-to-be ex** since you believe that you two are going to get a divorce soon. My original post above applies to people who are about to get married, the exact opposite of what the OP was asking for (people who are about to get divorced) so I hope I clarified everything.

Comment: The OP is already married to this person.  Fiancée is not correct.

Comment: Op's question was barely readable, @danebrck answered what it thought was the question.

Comment: The question is about someone who is about to be divorced. A fiancée is is someone you are about to marry. To equate this displays a shocking (if possibly realistic) sarcastic view of the marital institution.

Comment: @oerkelens haha quite true. I hope to not make more silly mistakes like these in the future but I wanted to keep this here to remind me to double-check before posting.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to word it as something like "she is my wife, **for the time being**" or "she is my wife, **at least for the moment**". Both of those imply that divorce may be imminent.

Depending on the situation, you could say "she is my wife, [in name only](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031477/)", which would strongly imply a loveless relationship but not necessarily one that is likely to change soon.

I can't think of any single words for this situation that don't add an undesirable amount of ambiguity.